# Win8 Desktop vs Win8RT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, tablet

We are developing a lightswitch app that will have a silverlight plug in controller that will allow for handwriting recognition and translation. we want to use this exclusively on a win8 tablet. we know that it has to be used on the desktop side of the tablet. We also know that the win8rt side has access to different tools that allow of handwriting recognition. (InkManager class) - is there any way to get access to these necessary classes from the desktop side of the win8 tablet.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx) by Scott Hanselman might help you.

Quote:

> I was trying to access some of the sensors that are built into this
>   Intel Ultrabook that runs Windows 8. However, while there's support
>   for Location Sensors built into the .NET 4 libraries on Windows 7 and
>   up, I want to access the complete Sensor and Location Platform that is
>   built into Windows 8 itself. Those APIs are available via COM and I
>   could call them via COM, but calling them via the WinRT layer is so
>   much nicer. Plus, this is kind of why WinRT exists.

There's also an example using VB.NET on [TheCodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457335/How-to-call-WinRT-APIs-from-NET-desktop-apps)